# SQLite: асинхронная запись в БД (2 варианта / как лучше?)

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Пишу бота на aiogram + sqlite. Точнее, бот написан и работает, а я думаю об улучшениях.

Есть вопрос по БД, как более верно работать с SQLite, чтобы это было надёжно, быстро, асинхронно. И вообще принимаю замечания по оптимизации кода. Я новичок.

1. На данный момент у меня работа с БД сделана с помощью класса:

```
class BotDB:

    def __init__(self, db_file):
        """Инициализация"""
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

# пара функций для примера:

    async def user_exists(self, user_id):
        """Есть ли такой пользователь (по id)"""
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 "
                                         "FROM users "
                                         "WHERE user_id = ?)", (user_id,)).fetchone()
            return bool(result[0])

    async def user_add(self, user_id, name=None, user_status=None):
        """Добавление пользователя"""
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(user_id, user_name, user_status) VALUES (?, ?, ?);",
                                (user_id, name, user_status,))
            return self.connection.commit()

# ... и много других.
# и в конце закрытие:

    def close(self):
        """Закрытие соединения"""
        self.connection.close()
```

Всё ли нормально написано и грамотно? Это рабочий вариант?

Вызываются функции так:

```
if not await BotDB.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
    await BotDB.user_add(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.username)
```

2. Есть другой вариант. Более асинхронный, как я это понимаю. С помощью aiosqlite.

Как это в классе написать, я не понял, но можно отдельными функциями:

```
import aiosqlite


async def user_exists(user_id):
"""Есть ли такой пользователь (по id)"""
    async with aiosqlite.connect("db/filedb.db") as db:
        async with db.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 "
                              "FROM users "
                              "WHERE user_id = ?)", (user_id,)) as cursor:
            result1 = await cursor.fetchone()
            result = bool(result1[0])
        return result
```

И так в каждой функции. Подключаемся к файлу и т.п. И это смущает, что каждый раз мы подключаемся. Хотя может я зря переживаю и просто не понимаю как это работает.

Рабочий ли второй вариант 2? Имеет ли он преимущества перед вариантом 1?

Благодарю за любую обратную связь.

Comment: В первом варианте то что вы обернули синхронные функции в асинхронные - это не сделало код асинхронным. Допустим, если у вас будет какой-то запрос с большим ответом, база будет долго его отдавать, и все это время ваша программа будет простаивать. Обращение к базе через асинхронную обертку в теории должен позволять остальной программе продолжать работу, пока одна из асинхронных функций ожидает результата от базы. На мелких запросах и с небольшой нагрузкой вы конечно разницы не почувствуете, но она есть.

Comment: Я думаю в асинхронном варианте вы можете сделать точно так же как и в синхронном: не использовать with ... connect, а сделать просто connect в конструкторе, только асинхронный. Тогда разницы в коде почти не будет между синхронной и асинхронной версией. Нет необходимости открывать-закрывать коннекшен каждый раз, если за них у вас нет борьбы между пользователями/потоками и если вы не боитесь потерять данные при внезапном завершении программы. Но в остальном, как уже написал insolor, желательно весь код переписать на асинхронный, чтобы от асинхронности был толк.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, стало понятнее. Примерно так и думал. И знаю, что sqlite синхронная сама по себе.

Comment: @CrazyElf, не совсем понял ваш ответ. Что значит сделать connect в конструкторе? Примерно это как?

Я знаю, как сделать в классе, но там __init__ нельзя сделать с async. Вот в чём проблема. Поэтому я использовал вариант 2. 

Если использовать вариант 2, то это ОК в целом?

Comment: @CrazyElf:

Главный вопрос у меня. Как переписать код на асинхронный? Второй вариант вроде бы и есть то, что нужно, ведь так?

Comment: @AlexanderA.XO по идее да, второй вариант будет асинхронным (по крайней мере, не будет блокировать остальной асинхронный код при запросах). Судя по описанию, там все запросы в отдельном потоке запускаются (один поток на соединение): https://github.com/omnilib/aiosqlite#details

Comment: Ну вместо `self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)` написать `async aiosqlite.connect("db/filedb.db")`, чтобы не писать каждый раз это по месту. Хотя я не прав, это не так просто сделать, там придётся исхитряться https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128325/how-to-set-class-attribute-with-await-in-init